# Вывод из двух связанных моделей ForeignKey на DJANGO

Tags: python, django

Функционал: вывод результатов спортсменов.

models.py:

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.DateField()
    federation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(
    blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.title


class Athlete(models.Model):
    athletename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.athletename


class AthleteResult(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey('contest.Contest', related_name='resultcontest')
    athlete = models.ForeignKey('contest.Athlete', related_name='resultathlete')
    place = models.SmallIntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    point = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    moneyprize = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s / PLACE: %s' % (self.athlete, self.contest, self.place) 

    class Meta:
            ordering = ["athlete"]
```

В первой таблице пишется название, год, федерация, описание. Во второй список атлетов с какими-то личными данными, в третьей их результаты. Каждая строка ссылается на атлета и на соревнование. Для связки два ключа ForeignKey

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Contest, Athlete, AthleteResult
from .forms import ContestForm


def contest_detail(request, pk):
    contest = get_object_or_404(Contest, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'contest/contest_detail.html', {'contest': contest})


def get_result(request, contest_id):
    athleteres = get_object_or_404(AthleteResult, pk=contest_id)
    return render(request, 'contest/contest_detail.html', {'athleteres': athleteres})
```

contest_detail.html - страница вывода каждого соревнования

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'contest_list' %}">Back</a>

    <div class="contest">
        <p>{{ contest.year }}</p>
        <h2>{{ contest.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ contest.description|linebreaks }}</p>

        <div class="contest_scorecard">
            <h1>Scorecard</h1>
                {% for athlete in athleteres %}
                    <li>{{ athlete.athlete }}</li>
                    <li>{{ athlete.place }}</li>
                    <li>{{ athlete.category }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Как вывести имена, места и категории? Так не работает, пробовал через filter() и всяко разно по-другому, все равно итог один.

Выводится только информация о соревновании из первой функции **contest_detail**. Возможно можно ссылаться только на третью модель и из нее использовать все остальные? Подскажите как лучше, и как чтобы работало, сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам надо вывести информацию о соревновании и связанных с ним результатов и атлетов, то используйте [связи](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects). В шаблоне тоже можно обращаться к связанным объектам.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'contest_list' %}">Back</a>

    <div class="contest">
        <p>{{ contest.year }}</p>
        <h2>{{ contest.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ contest.description|linebreaks }}</p>

        <div class="contest_scorecard">
            <h1>Scorecard</h1>
                {% for result in contest.resultcontest.all %}
                    <li>{{ result.athlete }}</li>
                    <li>{{ result.place }}</li>
                    <li>{{ result.category }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: А чтобы выводить, например, country и height?

Нужно использовать:
    {% for info in contest.resultathlete.all %}
                    <li>{{ info.height }}</li>
                    <li>{{ info.country }}</li>
     {% endfor %}

Я попробовал, так не работает.

Comment: В вашем случае info - это объект AthleteResult, если надо вывести информацию об атлете, то воспользуйтесь связью info.athlete, и выводите все, что вам нужно из модели Athlete. {% for info in contest.resultathlete.all %} <li>{{ info.athlete.height }}</li> <li>{{ info.athlete.country }}</li> {% endfor %}

Comment: В моем случае тогда и городить не нужно ничего получается, просто вывожу там же: {{ result.athlete.country }}. Буду подробнее изучать связи

Comment: Да, информацию об атлете можно через результат вытащить. Попробуйте нарисовать связи со стрелосками на каком-нибудь конкретном примере, не привязываясь к джанго и языку программирования, будет более наглядно. Потом можно сверху проставить названия моделей, а над стрелочками прописать названия связей.